# I could not get print() and debugPrint() value during Flutter test at gitlab ci

Tags: flutter, gitlab, continuous-integration

I put this code in flutter app.

```
if (Platform.environment.containsKey('FLUTTER_TEST')) {
debugPrint('test-text');
}
```

then I ran flutter test on gitlab CI.

```
flutter test -r json > result.json
```

I expected I could get Flutter test results and this debugPrint information but I could get it.
Do you know how to get print info at gitlab

Comment: Is the whole first line in your code snippet commented-out? If so, mis-matched curly brackets may be causing an issue.

Comment: Thank your comment. // is my mistake. i removed it but still print is not working.

Comment: If you copy and paste your actual code, you don't have to worry about typos or new errors.